# Migrating to Cocoa Pods from Submodules (Xcode iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm migrating from submodules to Cocoa Pods. After moving over I have a strange error when I build.

> error: unable to open
>   '/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-gzbqnssczmguxecctczxyqqjktqs/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/myapp.app.dSYM':
>   No such file or directory

I've **Product > Build Clean** but get it when running. I don't entirely get derived data, but my understanding is that once I've **pod install** and run the workspace (as opposed to the project) this should run properly and this missing dSYM should be accessible?

I have actually two build failures, the second being around a different pod, but I'll assume an answer on the more basic question might lead me to an answer on the second.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would suggest you simply clean the complete derived data. You can do this by going to `Window-> Projects` and then simply pressing the delete button beside of derived data. 
[image: Screenshot]

Once you delete that the project should build newly, also creating a new `.dysm`
Now just build and run and you should be good to go.

Hope that helps, Julian.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This is what I would have thought to. In fact I delete derived data regularly using a bash script. However the same error remains even after a clean build and deleting derived data from within XCode manually.